# React: How to add onChange functionality inside of Function component using React Hooks? Need onClick event from a checkbox to influence input state

Tags: reactjs, onclick, onchange, react-hooks

I have a function component with a checkbox and an input. I'm trying to create an onChange function for the checkbox that clears the input and disables it whenever a user clicks it by implementing the `useState` React Hook. Does anyone have any experience with Hooks who's done something like this before? I'm trying to look at code samples to better wrap my head around this as I'm still new to React Hooks

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {
  Col, Row, Icon, Input, Tooltip
} from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'

const CustomerDetails = ({ customer }) => {
  if (customer === null) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col span={24}>
            <ErrorContainer>
              <Icon type="exclamation-circle" />
            </ErrorContainer>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>{customer.contact.name}</h2>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Primary Contact:</strong>
          </H3>
          <P>{customer.contact.name}</P>
          <P>{customer.contact.phone}</P>
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Service Address:</strong>
          </H3>
          <P>{customer.site.address1}</P>
          <P>{customer.site.address2}</P>
          <P>
            {customer.site.city},&nbsp;{customer.site.state}&nbsp;
            {customer.site.postalCode}
          </P>
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Billing Address:</strong>
          </H3>
          <P>{customer.account.billingStreet}</P>
          <P>
            {customer.account.billingCity},&nbsp;{customer.account.billingState}
            &nbsp;
            {customer.account.billingPostalCode}
          </P>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      <Row>
        <Col span={10}>
          <h4>
            PRIMARY CONTACT EMAIL &nbsp;
            <Tooltip
              placement="topRight"
              title={primaryContact}
            >
              <StyledTooltipIcon
                type="question-circle"
                theme="filled"
              />
            </Tooltip>
          </h4>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledInput value={customer.contact.email} />
        </Col>
        <Col span={2} />
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledCheckbox /> EMAIL OPT OUT{' '}
          <Tooltip
            placement="topRight"
            title={emailText}
          >
            <StyledTooltipIcon
              type="question-circle"
              theme="filled"
            />
          </Tooltip>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}

CustomerDetails.propTypes = {
  customer: PropTypes.object
}

CustomerDetails.defaultProps = {
  customer: {}
}

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`
const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  input + span {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    background-color: transparent;
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    transition: none;
  }

  input:checked + span {
    border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }

  input + span:after {
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    left: 20%;
    transition: none;
    width: 12.5px;
    height: 20px;
  }

  input:disabled + span:after {
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.gray};
  }

  input:not(:checked):hover + span:after {
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.gray};
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  input:focus + span {
    border-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primary};
  }
`

const StyledInput = styled(Input)`
  max-width: 100%;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`

const ErrorContainer = styled.div`
  /* margin-left: 25%; */
`

const StyledTooltipIcon = styled(Icon)`
  color: #1571da;
`

const H3 = styled.h3`
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
`

const H4 = styled.h4`
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #1590ff;
`

const P = styled.p`
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
`

export default CustomerDetails
```

Comment: To clarify, you want the input field to be cleared and disabled whenever the checkbox gets clicked, regardless of what the original value of the checkbox was? Do you want the input to become active again if the checkbox is clicked again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `useState` hook to create a state variable that tracks whether the user has clicked the checkbox to disable the other input. The [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) is a function that takes an initial value and returns a state variable and a function used to update the value of that state variable (which works pretty much the same as `setState` but only for a single state variable).

For example:

```js
const [x, setX] = React.useState(1); // `x` is initially 1, but that will change on later renders

setX(prevX => prevX + 1); // increments `x` for the next render;
```

You'll also need to create an event handler function to respond to the clicking of this checkbox.

Here is a full example:

```js
import React from "react";

const MyComponent = props => {
    const [disableInputIsChecked, setDisableInputIsChecked] = React.useState(false);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

    function clearInput() {
        setInputValue("");
    }

    function handleInputChange(event) {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleCheckboxClick(event) {
        if (!disableInputIsChecked) { // this click was to check the box
            clearInput();
        }
        setDisableInputIsChecked(prevValue => !prevValue); // invert value
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" value={ disableInputIsChecked } onChange={ handleCheckboxClick }/>
            <input type="text" value={ inputValue } onChange={ handleInputChange } disabled={ disableInputIsChecked }/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvxMgV).

Probably you'll want to come up with better names for these values, but hopefully you get the point here.

Comment: This is awesome thank you! My only remaining question is that I'm populating the input with a ```defaultValue``` on render and when I click to disable the input the value isn't clearing. What do I need to change to enable that clearing function to work with a pre set default value?

Comment: @JCalkins89 hmm, that might be a product of the component you're using since it'll interpret `""` as basically no value, indicating that the default should be used. I'm not sure what component you're using, but a way around this would be to put the default value as the default/initial value for `inputValue` in my example (using `useState(defaultValue)`). That is, if you're okay with working outside of the input component you're using. (example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOqLOJ, and the default could also come from props if that's a use case for you)